# getting incorrect utc to local time for timezone given

Tags: python, datetime, utc

If I run this url : https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=12.98&lng=77.61&date=2017-08-26

I get **sunrise** time:     "12:38:14 AM"
and this is UTC time, if I convert it to given timezone using :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from dateutil import tz

def convertUTCtoLocal(date, utcTime, timezone):
    """ converts UTC time to given timezone
    """
    to_zone = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    from_zone = _tz.gettz('UTC')
    utc = _datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (date, utcTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    local = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
    return str(local.time())
```

but this returns `18:08:16` which is **evening** time , so what am I doing wrong here.

given timzone is `Asia/Kolkata`

**Example:**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
>>> to_zone = tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')
>>> utc = datetime.strptime('2011-01-21 02:37:21', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> utcTime = "12:38:16" ## from json URL we get AM/PM but I remove it.
>>> utc = datetime.strptime('2017-08-26 {}'.format(utcTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> utc
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 26, 12, 38, 16)

>>> utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
>>> central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
>>> central
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 26, 18, 8, 16, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata'))
```

Comment: Can you give and example for date, utcTime and timezone?

Comment: @ands : sorry bout that I hav updated it.

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out, please add set of example for arguments of function convertUTCtoLocal.

Comment: added example set.

Comment: I am stuck with this , I cannot deploy my app until this is fixed :(

Comment: I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you had "12:38:16 AM" which is actual "00:38:16" so you can't just strip "AM". I changed your function so it will work with "AM" and "PM" hours, just don't strip "AM" and "PM" before using the function:

```
import pytz
from _datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

def convertUTCtoLocal(date, utcTime, timezone):
    """ converts UTC time to given timezone
    """
    to_zone = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
    ## for formating with AM and PM hours in strptime you need to add
    ## %p at the end, also instead of %H you need to use %I
    utc = datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (date, utcTime), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
    utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    local = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
    return str(local.time())


date = '2017-08-26'
utcTime = '12:38:14 AM' ## Don't strip AM or PM
timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
x = convertUTCtoLocal(date, utcTime, timezone)
print(x)
```

Also, you can see working example [here](https://repl.it/HDFz/1).